# How can i filter by value Angular Array or Angular model?

Tags: angular, filter, model

I have this kind of data that I pulled from my service and I'm importing it into an angular model. What I want to do here is to find those whose `boolresult` value is `true` in the model. I used the find method for this, but there is only 1 element, I want to get all of them, how can I achieve this?

Example Array

```
[
    {
        "ownername": "Owner",
        "result": "Result1",
        "clientname": "ClientName1",
        "boolresult": true,
        
    },
    {
        "ownername": "Owner",
        "result": "Result2",
        "clientname": "ClienName2",
        "boolresult": true,
        
    },
    {
        "ownername": "Owner",
        "result": "Result3",
        "clientname": "ClienName3",
        "boolresult": false,
        
    },
    {
        "ownername": "Owner",
        "result": "Result4",
        "clientname": "ClienName4",
        "boolresult": false,
        
    }
]
```

Here is the code I tried to convert this result to a model and show only the true ones.

```
private getAllResults(){
    let apiEndpoint = "results"
    this.httpRequestService.getApi(apiEndpoint, false).subscribe(resultRequest => {
      
      this.serviceResults = resultRequest; // This is Array to MyModel
      this.serviceResults.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.createddate).getTime() - new Date(a.createddate).getTime());
      console.log(this.serviceResults)
      
      this.approvedResults = this.serviceResults.find(item => item.boolresult == true) // I Tried this
      console.log(this.approvedResults)
      
    })
    
  }
```

When I try this way, only 1 element is showing, I want to show all the values with `boolresult` `true`.How can I provide this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user filter method rather than find method

**find()**=> The first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function

**filter()**=>A shallow copy of a portion of the given array, filtered down to just the elements from the given array that pass the test implemented by the provided function

```js
var serviceResults=[
    {
        "ownername": "Owner",
        "result": "Result1",
        "clientname": "ClientName1",
        "boolresult": true,
        
    },
    {
        "ownername": "Owner",
        "result": "Result2",
        "clientname": "ClienName2",
        "boolresult": true,
        
    },
    {
        "ownername": "Owner",
        "result": "Result3",
        "clientname": "ClienName3",
        "boolresult": false,
        
    },
    {
        "ownername": "Owner",
        "result": "Result4",
        "clientname": "ClienName4",
        "boolresult": false,
        
    }
]
var approvedResults = serviceResults.filter(item => item.boolresult == true) // I Tried this
console.log(approvedResults)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let sampleArray = [
  {
    ownername: "Owner",
    result: "Result1",
    clientname: "ClientName1",
    boolresult: true
  },
  {
    ownername: "Owner",
    result: "Result2",
    clientname: "ClienName2",
    boolresult: true
  },
  {
    ownername: "Owner",
    result: "Result3",
    clientname: "ClienName3",
    boolresult: false
  },
  {
    ownername: "Owner",
    result: "Result4",
    clientname: "ClienName4",
    boolresult: false
  }
];

// Get all the results whose boolresult is 'true'
// Solution - 1
sampleArray = sampleArray.filter((element) => element.boolresult);
console.log("Result ==>>", sampleArray);

// Solution - 2

let result = [];
    sampleArray.forEach(element => {
      if (element.boolresult) {
        result.push(element)
      }
    })
```